# Intersection point of n singly linked list

Tags: algorithm, linked-list, singly-linked-list, intersection

I had given a technical interview in which I have been asked to find intersection point of n link list.
I could come up to find intersection point of 2 link list but couldn't extend it.
Could someone help me reach the algorithm

I tried to call the function to find integration point of 2 link list for every pair, but that didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

For finding intersection point of 2 link list:

1. Get the count of both the link list, suppose the bigger list is k nodes greater than second.
2. Traverse k nodes in the bigger link list, then then start comparing nodes of both the link list.
   If they match, then you have found the intersection point.

I had come up with this method to find the intersection of 2 link list, but I am somehow not able to extend it for 'n'.
Could we extend this to find intersection of n link list, or do we have to use map based approach only.